# Import and Use django Model Class using variable

Tags: python, django

I am new to both python and django.
First of all I am trying to do database query by using standard django feature . I dont want to use raw SQL.

What i want to achieve:

```
I want import and use Django Class  dynamically by using variable
```

like:

```
dynamic_var = "Note"
#import
from .model import dynamic_var
#query
q = dynamic_var.objects.all()
print(q)
```

but above code are not working. I know there are some solid reason behind it, because dynamic_var is a String not a Class/model class.
But how can i achieve this behavior.

```
dynamic_var = "Note"
from .model import Note

## Not work but i want to achieve 
info = dynamic_var.objects.all()

# Working
info = Note.objects.all() 

print(info)
```

Error

```
AttributeError at /note/
'str' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access to models using below style:

```py
from django.apps import apps

list_of_your_models = apps.get_models()
```

then you have access to your classes and can find your specific model throw iterate on the list.

There is also an another method in apps.

```
my_model = apps.get_model('<APP_NAME>', '<MODEL_NAME>')
```

Comment: Could you please share a example.how can i make standard django query in the iteration. like objects.all() or some CRUD operation

Comment: `my_model = [x for x in list_of_models if x.__name__ == "Note"][0]` then you can get objects using `my_model.objects.all()`

Comment: Thanks Man, Your Both tricks work, Last question is it efficient/best way, to do

Answer (score 4):

You can use get_model and pass the dynamic_var as a string parameter.

```
# models.py
dynamic_var = "Note"

# other file
from .models import dynamic_var
from django.db.models import get_model
model = get_model('myapp', dynamic_var)
model.objects.all()
```

Comment: `models.get_model()` was removed in Django 1.9. If you're running Django 1.9 and newer, you should use @Morteza Afshari's answer: `from django.apps import apps` and then `my_model = apps.get_model('<APP_NAME>', '<MODEL_NAME>')`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from django.apps import apps
    
def Name_view(request):
    models = apps.get_model('name_app', 'Name_model')
    models = models.objects.all()
```